# The [spread] tag has no description, and is being used for different contexts

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [spread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spread) tag is kind useless as it's being used in a bunch of different contexts (R, spreadsheets, <strike>but also javascript spread syntax</strike> actually, there were only a few javascript and typescript questions with the wrong tag, which I've fixed. In anycase - the tag should be given  description to prevent future confusion.)

It's the first tag that pops up as you type spread.

It looks like it mostly being used in relation to R.

In which case:

- A tag guideline should be given.
- The javascript questions with the [spread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spread) tag should be renamed [spread-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spread-syntax).

Comment: We should stop the [tag:spread].

Comment: We can certainly [spread] the burnination love

Comment: I think in general tags should not be words that can be used for a lot of different contexts.

Comment: We're [spread]ing the tag a bit thin

Comment: Someone else had been doing cleanup on the [spread] tag a few months ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373577/can-we-stop-this-from-spreading?rq=1

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's about Nutella.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart I just found out there's a tag `any`, and people actually use it!

Comment: It appears there are zero questions with the tag [tag:spread] currently.

Comment: It must be [spread]ing fast, then @TylerH because I see 116.

Comment: I think [spread] should be removed. In excel, converting [spread] to  [spreadsheet] makes more sense as it's clearer than using [spread] tag. I took a peek in R language and [spread](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.1/topics/spread) is just any function used in R, so I don't think there's any special reason to keep it in context of R related questions unless there's a better reason to keep it.

Comment: @Draco18s Ah, I think I didn't notice I was filtered to questions for 'Today' only. Annoying...